hetzner ubuntu dns resolution not working
I created a natgateway using opnsense
I created a VM in a private network which is behind the natgateway so that all internet traffic will pass through opensense into the client VM
I can ping google ip (142.250.190.142) through opnsense which works fine
but I can't ping the domain name www.google.com and also I can't update OS using apt update
I get error this
temporary failure in name resolution

I am using hetzner cloud provider for VMs
the archecture of hetzner is that de default gateway take the first ip address since servers are not connected directly. The flow is like this (client server > gateway > opnsense)
Interface config on the client VM
/etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto enp7s0
iface enp7s0 inet dhcp
   post-up ip route add default via 10.0.0.1
   dns-nameservers 185.12.64.2 185.12.64.1

IP address
opnsense router 10.0.0.2
VM 10.0.0.3
gateway 10.0.0.1



Why do you add route, and not use DHCP for this? Do you have a drawing for your topology? What does dig example.com @185.12.64.2 show?

@vidarlo I have updated my question with the diagram

I am getting network unreachable on dig example.com @185.12.64.2

Why do you have the add route statement? What is the IP of opnsense?

hetzner does not connect their servers directly. It uses a gateway to connect to each other. the gateway ip is 10.0.0.1. That is why I added it. The ip of opnsense is 10.0.0.2

Are you using your own gateway (opnsense) or hetzners? What are you attempting to achieve?

I am using hetzner default gateway. I am trying to route all traffic from the internet to the VM through opnsense natgateway

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Well, have you checked how /etc/resolv.conf look and ping'd 185.12.64.2 / 185.12.64.1?

Btw, while it's probably irrelevant to the problem stated here, I wonder why you have default via 10.0.0.1 instead of default via 10.0.0.2. And what's the point of the opnsense here if you are not using it as the default gateway (or really, it's pretty pointless as long as you have some other Internet gateway in the network).

@TomYan My default gateway is 10.0.0.1 because of the architecture of hetzner. Servers are not connected directly but through a gateway and the gateway takes up the first ip of the network

I edited this file /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and added dns


I edited this file /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and added dns

You don't want to do that.
If you want to stick with the debian networking stuff (i.e., /etc/network/interfaces; I never really know what it is called; ifup scripts?), delete the current /etc/resolv.conf (which should be a symlink), and use touch to recreate a empty regular file at the same path. Then restart this networking stuff, or maybe just reboot if you don't know how. After the reboot you should be able to see the nameservers being added to /etc/resolv.conf by this debian networking stuff.
Otherwise, stop using and disable this stuff and switch to systemd-networkd (and systemd-resolved).
Make sure you revert the change to /etc/systemd/resolved.conf in either case.
